# Error when install local package into anaconda using pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

Cannot install a local package into anaconda.

When I use  `sudo pip`

It's not installed into anaconda. (OS also has python)

Permission denied when used command pip without sudo(within anaconda).

Output from command pip install -e .:

```
Obtaining file:///home/jason/Downloads/findspark-master
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    writing findspark.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'findspark.egg-info/PKG-INFO'
```

Command "`python setup.py egg_info`" failed with error code 1 in `/home/jason/Downloads/findspark-master`

How to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Try upgrading pip first. If you think you do need sudo, just supply the full path to the correct pip executable and run `sudo /full/path/to/correct/pip ...`.

Comment: using `conda install --name package1 package2` should do the job

Comment: @Evert That works! I used `sudo $HOME/anaconda2/bin/pip...`, Thanks.

Comment: @dragon2fly This doesn't work and possibly conda couldn't install local package. My problem was solved, thank you anyway.